# How to get the position of a pyplot voxel during an onpick event?

Tags: python, matplotlib

There seems to be a difference between the artists of the standard 2D plotting functions like `.plot` or `.scatter` and the `Poly3DCollection` that `mplot3d` `.voxels` returns. I can't figure out how to get some sort of x, y, z position from the voxels that I click:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title('click on points')
voxels = ax.voxels(np.random.rand(10,10,10) > 0.95, picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):
    print(event.__dict__.keys())
    print(event.artist.__dict__.keys())
    # Nothing in the objects I get seems to contain x y z information.

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

I've tried looking through the `Poly3DCollection` API documentation and some base classes, I've tried to implement some code I've found inside of this [datacursor](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/blob/master/mpldatacursor/datacursor.py) package but I can't get it working.

The voxels are in an integer grid, so anything with integer precision is fine, if you can get me some sort of ID that I can map back to the voxel's position it's OK too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.artist` *is* the voxel you clicked on. You can locate it in the dictionary returned by `ax.voxels` to get its coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title('click on points')
voxels = ax.voxels(np.random.rand(10,10,10) > 0.95, picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):    
    for coords, voxel in voxels.items():
        if voxel == event.artist:
            print(coords)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I was missing the bit of information that ax.voxels returned a dictionary with coordinates for each voxel. Thanks! It takes some getting used to that dictionary keys can be any object in Python